# How do I tell PHPUnit where my tests are located?

Tags: php, phpunit

After spending several hours today searching and seeing several people having the same issue, I thought I turn to SO.

I run a WAMP stack; I have successfully installed PEAR and PHPUnit 3.6 using PEAR. I'm able to run phpunit over command line.

My WAMP folder is located at C:\wamp - I have several www folders - for sake of example let's say I have an MVC application located at C:\www\myproject.

```
/myproject
    /application
        /controllers
        /models
        /modules
            /forum
                /controllers
                /models
                /tests
                /views
        /views
    /public_html
    /tests
```

I'd like to know where PHPUnit is looking when I run something like

> phpunit ArrayTest

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is looking for your /tests in the current directory. Change (cd ..) to the directory containing your project and run phpunit.

Comment: Indeed - just twigged and close the question - always check CWD - :)

Comment: Btw: There is nothing in phpunit that looks in `CWD/tests`. It just recursively scans `.` / cwd.

Comment: @DanJ Not sure why you are pointing this out. Of course it is :)

Answer (score 7):

```
phpunit --help
PHPUnit 3.6.9 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [switches] <directory>
```

This means you have two options:

If you want to execute one test you can say:

```
phpunit myTest /path/to/my/test/php
```

or you can say

```
phpunit /path/to/my/projects/tests
```

and it will **recursively** scan the directory for all files ending in **Test.php** and execute all tests in those folders.

This is outlined in the [**`phpunit documentation regard test suite organisation`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) and in the help output and to be honest with you: I've never seen anyone having an issue with that so far :)

---

What is usually done is that people put a `phpunit.xml.dist` file in their project root.

In that file you can specify everything regard test location, test suite bootstrap and other configuration options. [**`Check the xml file docs`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html)

This allows you to just type `phpunit` and the tests will run.